# Moving LoginComponent to another slot

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Because of design requirements, we want to show the LoginComponent as part of the SiteLinks slot (above the main navigation). I went deep into the source code and found this component has a static mapping to the SiteLogin slot

```
export const defaultCmsContentProviders: ValueProvider[] = [
...
  provideCmsStructure({
    componentId: 'LoginComponent',
    pageSlotPosition: 'SiteLogin',
  }),
];
```

I have removed this provider from my set up, because redefining a `provideCmsStructure` with my slot name doesn't work.

I have defined a new ValueProvider[] for my project,

```
export const myCmsContentProviders: ValueProvider[] = [
  provideCmsStructure({
    componentId: 'HamburgerMenuComponent',
    pageSlotPosition: 'PreHeader',
  }),
  provideCmsStructure({
    componentId: 'LoginComponent',
    pageSlotPosition: 'SiteLinks',
  }),
];
```

This shows the hamburger on mobile, but doesn't add the LoginComponent to the SiteLinks slot..

Has anyone succeeded in moving this component?

We are running spartacus 4.0 (greenfield)

Comment: I have been able to resolve this by moving the LoginComponent in the SiteLinks slot in the CMS, not hardcoding it via `ValueProvider[]`

Answer (score 1):

I created a new page where I didn't want the Header to appear. I looked everywhere in my impexes to try to find out why this LoginComponent was being added even though I don't have a Header. In the end, it was hardcoded in the Spartacus library using provideCmsStructure and I still don't know how to remove it besides replacing it with a custom empty Component.

```
provideCmsStructure({
    componentId: 'EmptyComponent',
    pageSlotPosition: 'SiteLogin',
  }),
```

Surely there's a better way...